# React Native parameters inside image uri

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

I want to change the values of the following link and make it dynamic. So I want to make those hardcoded zipcodes to dynamic so I can do which zipcode I want.

In the following I want to be able to change `5611DE` dynamically.

```
<Image
    source={{ uri: 'https://openmapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?center=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7&locations=eindhoven,5611DE,...
/>
```

[image: I want to make those hardcoded zipcodes to dynamic so I can do which zipcode I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your zip code in a variable like `var zip;` and then add that 'zip' variable in that image url instead of static zip codes as follows:

```
source={{uri: `https://ope...map?center=eindhoven,${zip},kerk...hoven${zip},...`}}
```

so basically, you can write a string between `` this back tick character and add ${varialeName} whenever you want to add a variable in between the string.

Comment: Okay, I give that a try! Thank you for the response :)